# Populating dropdown list with dates in a week (PHP)

Tags: php, date, dropdown

how do you populate a dropdown list with dates in a week such as this week starts with 21 Mar 2016, the next item in the list is 22 Mar 2016 and so on.
Then when the next week starts again, that weeks' dates will take over the list again.

Comment: dupe of a dozen+ questions - tried anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP:

```
$mondayTimestamp = strtotime('monday this week');
$output = [];
for ($day = 0; $day < 7; $day++) {
    $output[] = date('d M y', strtotime(sprintf('+%d days', $day), $mondayTimestamp));
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<select name="days">
    <?php foreach ($output as $day) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $day ?>"><?php echo $day ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: a little sexier using the date-time class. http://au2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php